# elmah.axd System.NotImplementedException

Tags: asp.net, elmah

local works very well. Push it to server. it can store errors and email. but can't display elmah.axd. Always get error like below

System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.

web.config is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="casClientConfig" type="DotNetCasClient.Configuration.CasClientConfiguration, DotNetCasClient" />
      <sectionGroup name="elmah">
          <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
          <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
          <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
          <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
      </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
    <elmah>
        <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
        <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="ConnStr" />
        <errorMail from="xx@xx.xx" to="xx@xx.xx" subject="BC Runtime Error" async="true" smtpServer="xx.xxx" smtpPort="25"  />
    </elmah>
    <location path="elmah.axd">
  <system.web>
  <authorization>
  <allow roles="Admin" />
  <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
  </system.web>  
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="cc1" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="https://sso.xxx.xxx.edu/login" timeout="30" defaultUrl="~/Index.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="true" path="/" />
    </authentication>
    <sessionState timeout="120" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <membership defaultProvider="MyADMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="MyADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" connectionUsername="xxx\\grph-ccs" connectionPassword="contractprogrammer" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="DotNetCasClient" type="DotNetCasClient.CasAuthenticationModule,DotNetCasClient" />
        <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
        <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah"/>
    </httpModules>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
  </system.web>
  <location path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="index.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Faqs.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnStr" connectionString="data source=OFS684926;initial catalog=BldgCoord;user id=xxx;password=xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <!-- for sso-->
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <add name="Elmah" path="elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <remove value="index.aspx" />
        <add value="index.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <modules>
      <remove name="DotNetCasClient" />
      <add name="DotNetCasClient" type="DotNetCasClient.CasAuthenticationModule,DotNetCasClient" />
        <add name="Elmah.ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="Elmah.ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <!-- Other modules here -->
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <casClientConfig casServerLoginUrl="https://sso.xxx.xxx/login" casServerUrlPrefix="https://sso.xxx.xxx/" serverName="xxx/xxx.aspx" notAuthorizedUrl="~/NotAuthorized.aspx" cookiesRequiredUrl="~/CookiesRequired.aspx" redirectAfterValidation="true" renew="false" singleSignOut="true" ticketValidatorName="Cas20" serviceTicketManager="CacheServiceTicketManager" />
</configuration>
```

Comment: Show us your Web.config

Comment: I figure the problem is authorization. I use active directory which doesn't have role='Admin' I just want AD group="Manager" can see. How to implement that?